# How to concate a string and a enumerate type with macro in c++

Tags: c++

I want to concate a string and a enumerate name into string format. And then use them as input into some function. For example:

**define**

```cpp
// The following line doesn't work
#define CONCAT_STR_TYPE(str, type)  str ## type

enum EnumA{TEST=1};

void SomeFunction(const std::string &str)
{
  std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

**call**

```cpp
SomeFunction(CONCAT_STR_TYPE("test_", EnumA));
```

**Result**

```cpp
test_EnumA
```

The codes above don't work. I wander if there is a way to do so? If there is any way, please kindly show me.

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out. Define macro as following:

```
#define CONCAT_STR_TYPE(str, type)  str#type
```

Besides, this is not related to enumerate type. It works for other types.